# What are the benefits of using EJBs in a Webapplication?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, ejb, java-ee-6

I am developing a database driven web-application in Java EE and I am wondering about the benefits of using EJbs.

If I understand correctly it is best practice to use EJBs for every kind of business logic or database transaction.

I am using Hibernate as my JPA and here is my question:

What are the benefits of using an injected EJB as DAO instead of a regular Java class as DAO which gets called from my Managed Bean? And what is the difference?

I am new to Java EE, so this might be a beginner's question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use EJBs, you can use a number of very important services provided by the EJB container. The most important ones that are useful to pretty much anyone are dependency injection and declarative transactions. Both of these can alternatively be provided by the Spring framework. For very large applications, it can be useful that EJBs have a well-defined model for clustering, but you'll probably not need that.

Comment: So it is "ok" to just use regular classes for my business logic in a small application?

Comment: @tk2000: Even there you need transactions, and doing them manually is tedious and error prone. If you're already using a java EE server and thus have an EJB container available, it would be worth using EJBs just for that. Modern EJBs are very easy to use - all it takes are a few annotations, you don't have to deal with deployment descriptors and JNDI lookups anymore, so no reason to be afraid of them.

Comment: +1 for this answer. Dealing with transactions in JPA manually is a pain. An EJB is almost a normal class, just put @Stateless on top of it and don't create it with new but inject it. In 90% of the cases this is all you need to know.